# I'm getting a java.lang.NullPointerException: null error and I don't know what is missing

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, boolean

```
 public void FillArray()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < numEmp; i++)
    {
        employees[i] = true;
    }
}
```

I think this part may be the reason I'm getting the NullPointerException error, but I don't know what I'm missing. I have put my full code for the program below just in case there is something that is wrong with that that is giving me that error message.

//client class

```
public class Downsize
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        System.out.print("Do you want to downsize the company? (Y/N): ");
        String dummy = APIO.getString().toUpperCase();        
        while (dummy.equals("Y"))
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            System.out.print("Do you want to downsize the company? (Y/N): 
            dummy = APIO.getString().toUpperCase();
        }
    }
}
```

//object class

```
 public class Employee
    {
        int numEmp;
        int sprayer;
        int winner;
        boolean [] employees;

        public Employee()
        {
            System.out.print("How many employees? (0 to end): ");
            int numEmp = APIO.getInt();
            System.out.print("Who gets the spray can first?: ");
            int sprayer = APIO.getInt();
            FillArray();
            Selection();
            Winner();
        }

        public void FillArray()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < numEmp; i++)
            {
                employees[i] = true;
            }
        }

        public void Selection()
        {        
            System.out.println("EM="); //debugging method
            for (boolean em: employees)
            {
                System.out.println(em);
            }

            int complete = numEmp;
            while (complete > 1)
            {
                System.out.print("spraycan passed to #" + sprayer);
                if ((sprayer + 1) > numEmp)
                {
                    sprayer = 0;
                }
                while (employees[sprayer + 1] == false)
                {
                    sprayer++;
                    if (sprayer >= numEmp)
                    {
                        sprayer = 0;
                    }
                }
                employees[sprayer + 1] = false;
                System.out.print("  -  sprays #" + (sprayer + 1) + "'s hair");
                complete--;
                sprayer++;
                while (employees[sprayer] == false)
                {
                    sprayer++;
                    if (sprayer > numEmp)
                    {
                        sprayer = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void Winner()
        {
            if (sprayer == 0)
            {
                sprayer = 1;
                System.out.print("\nThe Winner is #" + sprayer);
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

//stack trace for the error message

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Employee.FillArray(Employee.java:22)
    at Employee.<init>(Employee.java:14)
    at Downsize.main(Downsize.java:9)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could show the stack trace to see where NPE occurs (and indicate which source line the line number corresponds to)

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by showing the stack trace

Comment: Your array is not instancied. Meaning the `employees` variable only contains a null pointer, hence the exception when you try to access `employess[i]`.

Comment: so how exactly would i instantiate the array using a boolean?

Comment: `employees = new boolean[numEmp];`

Comment: The stack trace is the multi-line message that tells you that you had a Null Pointer Exception.  Near the top of the stack trace, it will tell you which Java file and which line number the exception occurred on.  Start looking there.

Comment: @EmmaDillon the stack trace is what is printed out when the exception occurs. It starts with the type of exception (java.lang.NullPointerException), has a message, and then shows the lines of code/method calls being executed when the exception occurs. It generally provides very useful information about what you are doing when the exception occurs; you should always provide it if you are asking about an exception.

Comment: i'm still getting the error

Comment: Please provide your stack trace :) Edit your question and add it. Please also edit your code to show how/where you instantiate `employees`.

Comment: I added it into the question and where I instantiate employees is the first part of the question where i mention that I believe that is where the problem is

Comment: Please can you add the actual code, just so there is no confusion or ambiguity?

Comment: all of the code I have is presented in the question @Andy Turner

Comment: Your presented code does not contain `employees =`, so you are not currently instantiating the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must initialize the `employees` array. Once you read in the number of employees, do `employees = new boolean[numEmp];` (after the line `int numEmp = APIO.getInt();`). Otherwise, it is null, so trying to access `employees[i]` throws a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: so I should instantiate the array directly after I initialize the numEmp variable?

Comment: Not necessarily directly; somewhere after you initialize `numEmp` and before you call `FillArray`.

Comment: boolean [] employees = new boolean[numEmp];                                             like that?

Comment: Not quite. That is a local variable with the same name. Drop the first `boolean[]` to refer to the member variable.

Comment: Leave off the boolean[] part since you already declared it as an instance variable. So just "employees = new boolean[numEmp];"

Comment: I have an "<identifier> expected" error with "employees = new boolean[numEmp];"

Comment: this is what I have:                                                                                   int numEmp;
int sprayer;
int winner;                                                                                employees = new boolean[numEmp];

Comment: See my edit saying where to add in the line that I suggested.

Comment: The line `employees = new boolean[numEmp];` must occur after the line where `numEmp` is set to something.

Comment: "somewhere after you initialize numEmp and before you call FillArray". So, between the line where you write `numEmp = ...` and the line where you write `FillArray()`. For that matter, you should write `numEmp =` instead of `int numEmp =` and `sprayer =` instead of `int sprayer =`, otherwise you are declaring local variables, not initializing the member variables.

Comment: @mook where can i view that?

Comment: @EmmaDillon in the answer: "(after the line int numEmp = APIO.getInt();)"

Comment: that doesn't work. the first method is a constructor. it says it can't find variable employees if i put it there

Comment: employee**s**, not employee.

Comment: this is an object oriented program, so I can't change my instance data or anything in my constructor without getting an error message

Answer (score 1):

I see that you guys are beating around the bush in @mook's answer so let me just clarify so the OP can understand it well instead of guessing.

```
class Example {

    int size;
    boolean[] array;

    void initArray() {

        size = 5;
        array = new boolean[size];
    }
}
```

After *declaring* the size of the array and its type, you need to *initialize* the array. In the above example `array` holds 5 booleans.

If instead you write

```
class Example {

    int size;
    boolean[] array = new boolean[size];;

    void initArray() {

        size = 5;
    }
}
```

Then since `int` is set to 0 by default, the size of `array` will be 0 even if you change the variable you used to declare the size later in the code. This will give you an error since you will iterate up to 5.

@mook's answer is correct.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, so how do I instantiate the array so it is empty until i fill it with a boolean?

Comment: @EmmaDillon The variables in the array are not initialized when the array is initialized! It's very important to remember that. For primitives (like boolean), there are default values which are used. For objects, they are all set to null. If you want to initialize the objects in an array (or change the primitives default value), you have to iterate over the array and initialize each one.

Comment: I got it now! thank you so much for making it clearer

Comment: @EmmaDillon BTW, the default value for a boolean in Java is `false`, so my array in the first example holds 5 booleans each with a value of `false` when initialized. Arrays are never "empty", they always hold something (null is also something for this point).

Comment: okay. thanks for the tips. my program works now. thank you so much

Comment: @EmmaDillon Good job. You will want to accept an answer (the green checkmark) to mark the question as answered. (mook's answer is correct and he was first to answer, so it might be fair to choose his, albeit less detailed.) You can also upvote helpful answers regardless.